# Elasticsearch Query: Mismatch between values in the array and the array length

Tags: elasticsearch

Tried the following query to get the values of 2 array fields and their corresponding lengths, the array values and the lengths don't match.

**Query:**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "_source": ["file_types", "link_to_file"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": "45t8724b811b590d54cc1925166a9cb5"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "file_types_len": {
      "script": "doc['file_types'].length"
    },
    "link_to_file_len": {
      "script": "doc['link_to_file'].length"
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "_index": "my_index-150522",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "45t8724b811b590d54cc1925166a9cb5",
  "_score": 0.0,
  "_source": {
    "link_to_file": [
      "https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/abc123",
      "https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/wer134"
    ],
    "file_types": ["jpeg", "jpeg"]
  },
  "fields": {
    "file_types_len": [1],
    "link_to_file_len": [2]
  }
}
```

Both the arrays are of length 2 according the values returned, but the length for one of the arrays is says 1. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `file_types` array contains the same value twice (i.e. `jpeg`). Since your script works on [doc values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html), the array only contains a single instance of `jpeg`, no need for two.

If you want to retrieve the length of the arrays as they are present in the `_source`, then you can change your script to work on the `_source` field instead, like this:

```
params['_source'].file_types.length
```